# Ubuntu 18.4.03 restarts automatically 20 seconds after login on Dell Inspiron 5593

Tags: 18.04, dell, restart

I bought a new Dell laptop recently and installed Ubuntu on it today from a bootable disk. During installation,the screen turned black and displayed a bunch of error messages (which I didn't write down), but then the installation finished and I was able to log in. About 20 seconds after I logged in for the first time, Ubuntu rebooted. Now, when I try to run Ubuntu, it usually reboots itself within 20 seconds of me logging in. The other times, it freezes after I enter my password.

Any kind of troubleshooting I do is a race against the clock because I never have more than 20 seconds to do it. I managed to check that */proc/sys/kernel/panic* had a value of `0`, but that's all so far. I'm at a loss for how to proceed since I have so little time to do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Boiot from the "bootable disk" that you installed from, mount the failing system's disk, and look at the log filles.

Comment: That surprisingly didn't work. I couldn't get it to boot from the bootable drive. In the end, I just removed Ubuntu completely and re-installed it with the mininal installation and opting out of third-party software. It works fine now. I appreciate you taking the time to reply though, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! I just removed Ubuntu completely and re-installed it, this time with the mininal installation option and opting out of third-party software.